# How to monitor XBee GPIO data through X-CTU console?

Tags: sensors, xbee, zigbee, home-automation

I'm using PIR sensor for motion detection and XBee s2c for transmission. The remote(transmitting) XBee, connected to PIR, is configured as below

- CE=0
- DH=0
- DL=0
- D4=3
- IR=3E8 (500ms)
- IC=FF (Change Detection on all pins)

The base(receiving) XBee is configured as below

- CE=1
- DH=0
- DL=FFFF
- D4=5

At the base, GPIO4 is connected to an LED. I have performed a simple test as mentioned [here](https://www.digi.com/blog/community/xbee-broadcast-tech-tip-using-remote-at-commands-to-toggle-an-io/) to check whether the GPIO is working or not. It's working as mentioned with above given DH & DLs. As D4 is configured to 5, the LED glows all time. Theoretically, whenever PIR sends high, LED should be off and vice-versa.  But I am having two problems

1. The console of remote XBee is not showing any frames being sent but console of base XBee is showing the receiving frames and it is receiving correct data of PIR.
2. The pin D4 of base is not following the data being received i.e, it stays high all time.

I have observed the frames being received and they are showing the response of PIR as intended. How is the pin D4 not following the frames being received? I have followed [this](http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/XBee-802-15-4-Digital-Input-Output-Line-Passing) tutorial for DIO lines passing of XBee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're running the 802.15.4 (`ATVR`=0x20XX) or DigiMesh firmware (0x90XX) and not the ZigBee firmware (0x40XX).  Looking at the options in XCTU, I don't think ZigBee firmware supports I/O line passing.

And looking at that knowledge base article, you might need to set `ATIT` on the remote and `ATT4` and `ATIA` on the base.  If those registers aren't available, then you're probably running a firmware version that doesn't support I/O line passing.

Comment: This is the solution i'm looking for. I don't know that certain firmwares don't support DIO line passing. Been stuck at this point for three days. Thanks :)